# как достать элементы с ответа сервера

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Я отправляю запрос

```
vk.search.getHints(q='Привет', limit=10, search_global=1)
```

получаю ответ в форма json (Насколько я понимаю) как мне достать определенные строки типа id бесед человека и тд?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте разберемся, что в Python есть JSON-объект. Кажется, в общем виде это будет полезно упомянуть. Он представляется в виде комбинации типов данных `dict` и `list`, а также числа, строки и прочее.

Типичный JSON-объект:

```
{
    "key": {
        "nested_key_1": 1,
        "items": [
            {"item_key": "ABC"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Если декодировать его в объект языка Python и присвоить переменной `obj`, то до всех внутренних структур можно доступиться.

```
print(obj['key'])  # { "nested_key_1": 1, "items": [ {"item_key": "ABC"} ] }
print(obj['key']['nested_key'])  # 1
print(obj['key']['items'])  # [ {"item_key": "ABC"} ]
print(obj['key']['items'][0])  # {"item_key": "ABC"}
print(obj['key']['items'][0]['item_key']) # ABC
```

Не знаю, что за библиотека, но любая на запрос `vk.search.getHints(q='Привет', limit=10, search_global=1)` должна уже возвращать правильный объект, с которым можем взаимодействовать упомянутым выше образом.

Если открыть страницу с демонстрацией того, как работает запрос (надо быть залогиненным в браузере в ВК, если не быть залогиненным, то просто откроется подробная документация по методу) [https://vk.com/dev/search.getHints?params%5Bq%5D=Привет&params%5Blimit%5D=2&params%5Bsearch_global%5D=1&params%5Bv%5D=5.124](https://vk.com/dev/search.getHints?params%5Bq%5D=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82&params%5Blimit%5D=2&params%5Bsearch_global%5D=1&params%5Bv%5D=5.124) и изучить структуру объекта, то достать id людей и групп в список можно так:

```
group_ids = []
profile_ids = []
resp = vk.search.getHints(q='Привет', limit=10, search_global=1)
for item in resp['response']['items']:
   if item['type'] == 'group':
       group_ids.append(item['group']['id'])
   elif item['type'] == 'profile':
       profile_ids.append(item['profile']['id'])
```